# How to find application working or down using ping command in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

Is there any command to find website is working or down in linux ? Hope ping command helps...but how to check return packets successfull or not ?

```
ping www.google.com
```

Please advise is there any way to find website is working or not using ping command in shell script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In script you can look for `echo $?` output after you test using `ping` as explained below. 
If the ping is successful which means the website is up, the echo output will return `0` else non-zero.

```
esunboj@L9AGC12:~$ ping 155.53.12.255
PING 155.53.12.255 (155.53.12.255) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 155.53.12.255 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2000ms

esunboj@L9AGC12:~$ echo $?
1
esunboj@L9AGC12:~$ ping 155.53.12.7
PING 155.53.12.7 (155.53.12.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 155.53.12.7: icmp_req=1 ttl=48 time=239 ms
64 bytes from 155.53.12.7: icmp_req=2 ttl=48 time=240 ms
64 bytes from 155.53.12.7: icmp_req=3 ttl=48 time=241 ms
^C
--- 155.53.12.7 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 239.250/240.304/241.451/0.985 ms
esunboj@L9AGC12:~$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Looks like your option good , But how to execute ctrl+c for exit from ping command in script ?

Comment: @openquestion right catch. How about using [ping](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) with `-c` count option limiting echo request by needed.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `ping` use this `telnet` command to make sure port 80 is open:

```
telnet www.domain.com 80
```

You can even send `HEAD` request after opening `telnet` session if website is not blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

Not every website responds to ping, and a successful ping does not prove the site is actually working correctly. With lynx, you can test the actual contents of a page:

```
lynx -dump www.google.com \
    | grep --silent '________' \
    && echo "Google search form found." \
    || echo "No Google search form found."
```

nmap will tell you if the port is listening:

```
nmap www.google.com -p 80
```

tcptraceroute will also tell you if a port is open:

```
tcptraceroute www.google.com 80
```

There's also wget, curl...

Answer (score 0):

ping send will send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to network hosts and on success it will receive  ICMP ECHO_REPLAY you can run tcpdump to verify